# Split string by multiple delimiters with Saving the delimiters

Tags: c#

I am trying to split a string by multiple delimeters.

I want to leave the delimeters in the array..

```
Delimeters = ["'", "-", " ", "."];
```

For example:

```
input = Mr. Olive n-th indices - al al's k-2

output = ["Mr", ".", " ", "Olive", " ", "n", "-", "th", " ", "indices", 
          " ", "-", " ", "al", " ", "al", "'", "s", " ", "k", "-", "2"]
```

I know that something like that will split it without saving the delimiters:

```
String[] tokens = input.split("'|-|\\.| ");
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.Split` does not support that.But you can write a simple method that does:

```
public static string[] SplitWithDelimiters(this string source, params char[] delimiters)
{
     var temp = new List<char>();
     var parts = new List<string>()
     foreach(var c in source)
     {
         if(delimiters.Contains(c))
         {
             if(temp.Any()) 
             {
                  parts.Add(new string(temp.ToArray()));
                  temp.Clear();
             }
             parts.Add(c.ToString()); 
         }
         else
         {
             temp.Add(c);
         }
     }

     return parts.ToArray();
}
```